# an obstructing working copy was found

Tags: svn, version-control

I've tried understanding why this is happening yet I don't know. Yet I can explain how to reproduce the issue.

Firstly, I make a project (with folders inside it which are trunk, branches and tags) and add it to a repository. I change directory to the trunk. I add the a file to version control then make a commit. Then I decide to make a branch ( q: does it matter what directory i'm in while I create a branch? ). I change directory to the project ( by this I mean if do ls I see branches, tags and trunk). And while in the project directory I do

```
svn copy https://repoURL/project_name/trunk/ https://repoURL/project_name/branches/newBranch -m "making new branch"
```

now I change directory to branches/newBranch and do

```
svn co https://repoURL/project_name/branches/newBranch
```

and then I decide to change directory to the project ( by this I mean if do ls I see branches, tags and trunk) and then I do svn update. This is where the message an obstructing working copy was found.

I tried searching around however, nothing really explained WHY. Everything was how to solve it. I want to know why so I can prevent it in the first place.

Many thanks.

```
    $ svn update
Updating '.':
Skipped 'branches/newBranch' -- An obstructing working copy was found
At revision 30.
Summary of conflicts:
  Skipped paths: 1
```

Comment: Are you checking out a working copy *inside* an existing working copy?

Comment: Yes that is correct I'm checking out the project and inside the branches folder which is inside the project I check out newBranch

Comment: If you `svn update` the newBranch (instead of the `svn checkout`), that will sync your existing working copy rather than creating a nested obstructing working copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you mix the working copies by nesting them. That's a bad practice. Moreover, your working copy contains multiple branches of the same project. That's also a bad practice.

You should not checkout a working copy of the whole repository. Don't checkout the root of the repository or the root of the project. You don't need to have all the project's branches and tags in the same working copy.

Your working copy can be instantly switched to another development branch / tag / whatever. Moreover, Subversion repository can contain a number of (un)related projects and it's better to have a dedicated working copy for each of them, not a single working copy for all of the projects. What is more, you can have unlimited number of working copies on your computer.